# How to have multiple submit buttons for a quiz on one page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a language quiz and it requires multiple submit buttons on one page through which one can check their answers. Having one submit button works fine. But so far, having multiple submit buttons creates issues where one submit button, when pressed, generates two (if there are 2 questions) of the same answers under both submit buttons. So after one click you will see 4 of the same answers. And only one submit button will be disabled. See scripts below for more info.

Below you'll find the html form for 1 of the quiz questions.

```
<form id="formId">
<h5>1. I am strong</h5>
<p>Translate the above sentence.</p>
<input type="text" id="q1" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="submitId" value="Check answer" />
</form>
```

Below you'll find the javascript that gives the answer when submit button is clicked.

```
<script>
var answers = {
    "q1": ["Ik ben sterk"]
    
};
function markAnswers(){
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        console.log($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]));
        if($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]) === -1){
            $(this).parent().append("<br>The correct answer: Ik ben sterk");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().append("<br><font style='color:green;'>Correct!</font>");
        }
    })
}
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    markAnswers();
});
</script>
```

The script below is to make sure user cannot submit answer again.

```
<script>
var form = document.getElementById('formId');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitId');

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {

   // Disable the submit button
   submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

   // Change the "Submit" text
   submitButton.value = 'Check answer';
            
}, false);
</script>
```

Above scripts are just for one question. If I add another question and I copy paste scripts and change the ID's to q2, formId2 and submitId2 it will not work as described earlier. What do I need to change to the scripts in order for this to work? Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that you're using an h5 heading for you quiz question. Whether it should be a heading or not requires more context... but it should only be an h5 if your quiz is nested under an h4 heading. If you're using the h5 for a visual appearance, you can use a span & style it instead. Think of headings like a table of contents for your website. Using them improperly can make your site inaccessible. See: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator I use bootstrap to style the quiz and found that h5 has the right size compared to the normal text I use. But I have to go over the styling again as I'm using bootstrap 3 right now instead. Thanks for the information.

Comment: no problem! Most versions of Bootstrap (including 3) provide classes like "h1", "h2", etc to allow you to apply the default heading stylings to other elements. You could use something like <span class="h5">1. I am strong</span>. Check out the Typography section of the docs of the version of Bootstrap you're using. e.g. here's the latest: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/content/typography/

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator Okay cool, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `markAnswers` function is looping through all inputs, that's why you're getting the answers for all of them when you click any of the buttons.

You can fix this by changing the id of the forms to be like `formId1`, `formId2` etc., then giving that id to the `markAnswers` function.

Example:

```js
function markAnswers(id) {
  $(`#q${id}`).each(function () {\
    if ($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]) === -1) {
      $(this).parent().append(`<br>The correct answer: ${answers[this.id]}`);
    } else {
      $(this).parent().append("<br><font style='color:green;'>Correct!</font>");
    }
  });
}

$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const id = e.target.id.replace("formId", "")
  markAnswers(id);
});
```

Additionally, you can disable the button in the same submit event as well:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
  ...

  $(`#submitId${id}`).each(function () {
    this.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    this.value = "Check answers"
  })
  
});
```

Here's a working example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-dust-ylvdis)

Comment: Perfect! It works and it's better than ever! Thanks!